# Is there support for Word and Excel ouput formats in the BIRT API?

Tags: birt

I am generating ad-hoc reports on the fly in a servlet.  I see how to send a report back as HTML or PDF.  Does the BIRT API support other formats?  The BIRT runtime app performs these exports, but I don't see anything in the API.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Word and Excel are both supported(either 2003 and 2007) by birt engine.

You can set it into Report engine options :

```
HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();
options.setOutputFormat("xls");

task.setRenderOption(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

From tomcat, you can render it in these outputs by setting the url format parameter:

html:

```
http://server:8080/birt/output?__report=myReport.rptdesign&__format=html
```

pdf:

```
http://server:8080/birt/output?__report=myReport.rptdesign&__format=pdf
```

word doc:

```
http://server:8080/birt/output?__report=myReport.rptdesign&__format=doc
```

excel:

```
http://server:8080/birt/output?__report=myReport.rptdesign&__format=xls
```

The last two (doc and xls) don't render in-line on the page, it downloads the word .doc or .xls to the client computer.